# Webtask + Sendgrid = compilation failure?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, webtask

Running this via webtask.io :

```
var sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
module.exports = function(context, req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html '});
  res.end('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
};
```

Results in this response:

```
{
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Compilation failed: Unexpected token {",
 "error": "Unexpected token {",
 "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {\n    at 
   exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)\n    at Module._compile 
   (module.js:373:25)\n    at Module._compile 
   (/data/sandbox/lib/module.js:127:21)\n    at 
   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)\n    at Module.load 
   (module.js:343:32)\n    at Function.Module._load 
   (module.js:300:12)\n    at WebtaskModule.require 
   (/data/sandbox/lib/module.js:101:19)\n    at require 
   (/data/sandbox/lib/module.js:136:21)\n    at Object.<anonymous> 
   (/data/io/3bd979bebf074788b6849906721a8b06/webtask.js:2:14)\n    at 
   WebtaskModule.compileWebtask (/data/sandbox/lib/module.js:95:34)"
}
```

If I comment out the `@sendgrid/mail` module, everything runs fine. (And, yes, I've added the module to the webtask.)

Is it me, the module, or webtask?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not. The goal of the project was to learn webtask.io and not SendGrid, so I just moved on to some other modules and had no issues.

Comment: Ok - I think I know what the issue is now - we use Node 4.x by default and SG needs 8. Although I've used SG myself so that may not be it. I guess I'm useless here. ;P

Answer (score 2):

This is working in 2018 with `@sendgrid/mail@6.3.1`.